# How to get userId from access token for Gmail OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to create a web app that would fetch emails from a user's Gmail. I understand that I would require authentication via Google OAuth 2.0.

What I'm trying to do is setting a `watch()` request on an inbox. Then, when the watched inbox gets an email, I want to get notified. I'm using Google's [PubSub](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) API.

### What I've done

I followed the steps given in the [Gmail OAuth documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth), but am confused as to how to store multiple access tokens for multiple users.

So when the user first logs in using their Gmail account, I generate a code which I exchange for an access token. Then I store this in a database. However, when I get notified about an email, I only receive from the API the user's email address. I would like to do some further API calls for this user. So now I would need to retrieve the token for the specific user. But...

### The problem

... How do I store access tokens by email? I only have access to their token once they login/authorize. Is there any way of retrieving the email address from an access token? I could then store the access tokens as key-value pairs of `<email address>`->`<access token>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)-request immediataly as they log in for the first time, like so:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_THE_LOGGED_IN_USER>
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "emailAddress": "example@gmail.com", // Here is the user's email address.
 "messagesTotal": 6446,
 "threadsTotal": 4495,
 "historyId": "570232" // Here is the current historyId of his account.
}
```

Then, when you get a push request via `watch()`, you can use the `historyId` in the response above to [see what has happened](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list).